# Сauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I would  like to understand  statement of Cauchy  integral theorem,which says that

Cauchy's integral theorem implies that the line integral of every holomorphic function along a loop vanishes: or

[image]

where  γ is a rectifiable path in a simply connected open subset U of the complex plane C whose start point is equal to its end point, and $f : U → C$ is a holomorphic function.
  so  first  as  i know rectifiable means finite,also because we have such complex plane whose  start point is  the same as  end point,then does it means that it is similar to such situation when  we  have

$\int f(x)dx$ from $a$  to $b$  is equal to  $F(b)-F(a)$ and because  end  and start point is same ,then this  equals to zero? or  there is  two different path and they compensate each other?please help me to understand why this formula held?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-line proof exploiting holomorphic of $f(z)$, Cauchy-Riemann equations and Stokes' theorem

Note that $f(z)\,dz$ is a closed differential form so:

$\int\limits_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz = \int\limits_{\partial D} f(z)\,dz = \int\limits_D d[f(z)\,dz] = 0 $

The $D$ is the area bounded by $\gamma$ countour.

Comment: could you  be a little more detailed

Comment: Use some complex analysis book for detailed proofs of similar theorems. I studied this one few years ago http://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/shabat-all.pdf Chapter 2

Comment: This isn't quite true. The version of Cauchy integral theorem that the OP mentions is actually the Cauchy-Goursat integral theorem, whereas what your proof proves is the (classical) Cauchy integral theorem, in which $f'$ is assumed to be continuous (so that Green's/Stokes' theorem can be applied). Although some pointed out that the continuity of $f'$ can be made unnecessary, [a special version of Stokes' theorem](http://faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/Stokes.pdf) is needed.

Comment: and generally what does this theorem says?

Comment: @dato See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) on the theorem. The theorem's statement is essentially the same as yours, but this actually is not the original Cauchy integral theorem. The original theorem, discovered by Cauchy himself, assumes that $f$ not only is holomorphic, but also has continuous partial derivatives on $U$. Goursat later found a new proof, in which the condition that $f'$ is continuous is removed. To distinguish between these two versions of the theorem, some called Goursat's version the Cauchy-Goursat theorem.